# broadcast receiver throwing multiple broadcasts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

OK. I'm curious as to whether or not it's my code or if the Broadcast receiver is doing what its supposed to.  I set up a broadcast receiver to listen for changes in wifi such as whether a certain network is connected to or not. The broadcast receiver works and in the on receive method its post the info in the logcat.  the issue here is it seems to fire multiple times as in my this case like 8 times. is this what its supposed to do?  is there a way to limit the number of times it fires.

here is the log cat

```
07-12 13:33:21.748 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
07-12 13:33:21.753 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
SSID :: "SkyNet Global Defense Network "
07-12 13:33:21.754 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: Wifi is enabled
07-12 13:33:21.806 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
07-12 13:33:21.809 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: BSSID :: 
4c:60:de:cf:e3:88SSID :: "SkyNet Global Defense Network "
07-12 13:33:21.810 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: Wifi is enabled
07-12 13:33:21.862 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
07-12 13:33:21.865 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: SSID :: "SkyNet 
Global Defense Network "
07-12 13:33:21.866 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: Wifi is enabled
07-12 13:33:21.918 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
07-12 13:33:21.920 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: SSID :: "SkyNet 
Global Defense Network "
07-12 13:33:21.921 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: Wifi is enabled
07-12 13:33:21.966 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
07-12 13:33:21.969 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: SSID :: "SkyNet 
Global Defense Network "
07-12 13:33:21.970 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: Wifi is enabled
07-12 13:33:22.013 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
07-12 13:33:22.017 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: SSID :: "SkyNet 
Global Defense Network "
07-12 13:33:22.018 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: Wifi is enabled
07-12 13:33:22.073 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
07-12 13:33:22.075 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: SSID :: "SkyNet 
Global Defense Network "
07-12 13:33:22.076 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: Wifi is enabled
 07-12 13:33:22.386 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: 
 android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
07-12 13:33:22.391 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: SSID :: "SkyNet 
Global Defense Network "
07-12 13:33:22.392 8152-8152/com.apklegion.pcnotetest D/TEMP: Wifi is enabled
Wifi is  connected
```

and here is the broadcast receiver class

```
public class MyWifiStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

Boolean isConnected = false;
String skynet, message;
public static boolean isConn = false;

                           @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String action = intent.getAction();
                            Log.d("TEMP", action);


                            assert action != null;
                            if (action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {

                                NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);


                                if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                                    WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                                    WifiInfo wifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                                    String test = wifiInfo.toString();
                                    String sid = wifiInfo.getSSID();


                                    tv.setText(test);
                                    int count =0;

                                    Log.d("TEMP", "SSID :: " + wifiInfo.getSSID());
```

and in my Main Activity class, I registered the receiver as well as setting up unregistering and reregistering it in OnPause and On resume

```
   filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
    super.registerReceiver(myWifiStateListener, filters);

@Override
protected void onPause() {
   try {
       unregisterReceiver(myWifiStateListener);
       Log.i(TAG, "Unregistered broadcast receiver");
   }catch (Exception e){

    }
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Registered broadcast receiver");
    registerReceiver(myWifiStateListener,filters);
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
   stopService(new Intent(this, MyWifiStateListener.class));
    Log.i(TAG, "Stopped service");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: looks good to me. im pretty sure the device checks it every so often... which is probably why this is happening. use shared pref to store value...if tht value changes, sned a broadcast

Comment: all 8 happen at once its not over a period of time

Comment: oh. that is weird. whats the flow? why are you sending a broadcast if the user is connected to wifi?

Comment: The app listens for wifi connections and once  the phone has auto connected it sends a signal to a server I have on my pc.  The broadcast is to monitor which wifi and when that connection  happens.  Unless Theres another way to do it this way kinda works for now besides the extra broadcasts

Comment: can i ask why you want to know which wifi someone connects to? why does it matter?

Comment: There are multiple networks in my home. my pc is connected to a specific network and the server is listening to ports on that same network so it has to know which one to connect to.